# Why are arguments independent of singular/plural in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

It seems like python script arguments defined with argparse are independent of the form (singular/plural) in which they are provided. Specifically, if one defines a sample script `script.py` as follows:

```py
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--names",
        type=str,
        required=True,
    )

    args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    print(vars(args), unknown_args)
```

When it is called with the below argument, the following is printed

`python script.py --name test_name` -> `{'names': 'test_name'} []`

And similarly, when it is called the below argument, the following is printed

`python script.py --names test_name` -> `{'names': 'test_name'} []`

Is this an expected behaviour? I could not find anywhere an answer to that question.

Comment: Default behavior is to allow abbreviations.  That can be turned off (in recent versions).  See the docs.

Comment: It has nothing to do with plurals. You can also shorten it to `--na`

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching): *"The `parse_args()` method by default allows long options to be abbreviated to a prefix, if the abbreviation is unambiguous (the prefix matches a unique option)[...]An error is produced for arguments that could produce more than one options. This feature can be disabled by setting `allow_abbrev` to `False`."*